# Show only second level menu items?

Tags: menus, navigation

Something like this. I would like to get only the second level menu items, not their parent items.

Home

- Sub Menu Item 1
- Sub Menu Item 2

About

- Sub Menu Item 3
- Sub Menu Item 4

For example, from this list I'd like an output of something like.

```
<ul id="home_submenuitems">
    <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="about_submenuitems">
    <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    <li>Sub Menu Item 4</li>

</ul>
```

I have been at this for weeks now, no answer I found on this site or any other has helped.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how good your programming skills are, but the example under **Using a Custom Walker Function** [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) should give you a good idea of what you have to do. If you need further advice, comment

Comment: Can you please make this a real answer - take a look at [answer].

Comment: Still learning, as well, but I think it obeys this rule: "but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful [...]", doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, but dropping names and links is just not always as helpful as one might think. For example the possible duplicate i suggested offers way more information on the specific topic then your link; and I didn't posted that as answer for a reason. Besides that, I'm just saying, if you're able to provide a real solution, not just a hint, do it.